# How to configure DB in a Flask app dynamicly?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm working on app, where user have to enter database connection parametrs by hands

So I've made an api here it is:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask import Flask, request
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)


# /hello
@app.route("/hello", methods=['GET'])
def hello():

    return "Hello word"


# /get_tables
@app.route(f"/get_tables", methods=['GET'])
def get_tables():

    host = request.args.get('host', type=str)
    user = request.args.get('user', type=str)
    password = request.args.get('password', type=str)
    database = request.args.get('database', type=str)

    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = "localhost"
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = "root"
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = "password"
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = "restaurant"

    mysql = MySQL(app)

    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "SHOW TABLES"
    cursor.execute(query)
    records = cursor.fetchone()
    print(records)
    return records
```

"hello" endpoint is working fine, but when run "get_tables" I recieve an error:

`AssertionError: The setup method 'teardown_appcontext' can no longer be called on the application. It has already handled its first request, any changes will not be applied consistently. Make sure all imports, decorators, functions, etc. needed to set up the application are done before running it.`

I also was trying to debug my api and found out that errorr ocures on a  `mysql = MySQL(app)` line

What can I do to solve this problem? or maybe it's better not to use api at all and just connect to DB from ui?